# How to take user inputted number and assign to byte

Tags: java, android

I've got a user input dialog box which I'm using to update a value.

`byte valScoreAway = 0;`

The value of valScoreAway is displayed on the screen with:

`tvScoreAway.setText( valScoreAway );`

This works perfectly.

During the program the score will increment when the TextView tvScoreAway is clicked.
This works perfectly.

If there is an error, I have it so that a onLongClickListerner() will inflate a dialog box with an edit field.  The user will enter the correct value into the EditView and then click OK.  When the OK button is click, I am trying to assign the user inputted value to valScoreAway but it is failing because valScoreAway is a `byte` type and `userInput.getText()` is returning a string.

Basically, I need to convert the value of `userInput.getText()` to a byte type.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Byte.parseByte(userInput.getText().toString());
```

Comment: The method parseByte(String) in the type Byte is not applicable for the arguments (Editable)

Comment: I will just have to wait for the time to pass.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a edit text input to byte type. By using the following way :

```
String example = userInput.getText().toString();
example.getBytes();
```

Comment: Thank you...  This is another great answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
userInput.getText().toString().getBytes();
```

//convert string to byte

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `Integer.parseInt(userInput.getText())`? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Thank you.  I used Byte because the number isn't ever going to go that high.